# Algorithm name for all 2-uplets of a set

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm looking for the name (and for the code : in PL/SQL or PG/SQL) of the algorithm which is finding all couple (2-uplets) of a set.

Example : 
A - B - C
Result :
1 : A - B
2 : A - C
3 : B - C

I know that the powerset algorithm do this part of the job, but I'm looking for an optimised couple finder algorithm.

Link for the powerset pg/sql algorithm : https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060924054759.GA71934%40winnie.fuhr.org

Comment: It's called `tuplets` and you want to find `combinations`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen "tuplet" is a musical term. What OP is referring to is called a [`pair`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Comment: Added comment to my answer, in case you aren't notified.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like

```
Select A.x, B.x
From YourTable as A, YourTable as B
Where A.key <> B.key
```

You mention SQL so this might be preferable. Note that the number of rows in the cross product is about the same as the number of pairs, so it isn't terribly inefficient.

Comment: I have no keys in my data table. The table is like that : order | product
(No primary key and no unique value (order & product))

Comment: This solution is not working because it's creating double couple : for {A,B} => it's building : {A-B}, {B-A}. Or in the result we just need : {A-B}

Comment: @QuentinT. If the data you're putting in pairs is such that it can be put into a total order - that is, > or < could be defined - perhaps you could fix the problem you mentioned by changing the where clause to keep only the pairs where the first element is strictly less than the second? This total order doesn't need to be the "natural" order; and order will do, and most built in types have some order in which they can be put.

Answer (score -1):

I've build the solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION twouplets(a anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    retval  a%TYPE;
    size  integer := array_upper(a, 1);
    i       integer;
    j       integer;
BEGIN
    i := 0;
    j := 1;

    FOR i IN 1 .. size LOOP
    FOR j IN 1 .. size-i LOOP
    retval := '{}';
                retval := array_append(retval, a[i]);
                retval := array_append(retval, a[i+j]);
                RETURN NEXT retval;
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN; 

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION twouplets(anyarray)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```